# styling Radzen.Blazor components using css isolation in custom component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, radzen

We are using the Radzen Blazor library and adding some of our own flavor to the Radzen components.

I'd like to use the encapsulated css (scoped to the component) to make adjustments to the Radzen component styles instead of making changes to the global style sheet but since the Radzen components are their own components, I assume the css isolation would apply to them at their component level.

Is there a way to make stylistic changes to the radzen components w/o having to just make adjustments on the global css file?

I tried adding my own class overrides for the radzen defined class names and using `!imnportant` but that didn't take.

Edit:

Brian Parker's comment got it working for me for the most part.  I have a secondary question though.

inside my `::deep` pseudo element, I'm trying to add a css selector for when the `<body>` has a specific class applied.  That does not appear to take in my child component (the Radzen component).

ex code:

```
::deep {
  .rz-button {
    color: #fff;
    ...
  }
  .other-body-class .rz-button {
    color: red !important;
       }
}

.heading {
  color: blue;
}
.other-body-class .heading {
  color: red;
}
```

I included another selector (.heading) that does work on the component itself, but the nested Radzen button component does not get the new style when the body tag has the `other-body-class` class applied.  I'm assuming this is an issue with the `::deep` pseudo element but not sure.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Look at `::deep` with isolation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#child-component-support

Comment: Awesome - that did it!  I will accept an answer if you want to create it.

Comment: @BrianParker I edited my OP with some additional info about inheritance from more top level elements inside my `::deep` pseudo element.  If you can shed some light, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to simply explain CSS Isolation. When you render a component with CSS Isolation, an attribute is applied to the DOM elements in your component. This attribute is used to apply your CSS.

Note: You also need to wrap any other components in a DOM element for isolation to work, `::deep` will not apply to top level components in your component.

if you have this CSS:

```
::deep .SomeComponentClass {
    color: blue;
}
```

This won't work:

```
<SomeComponent />
```

But this will:

```
<div>
    <SomeComponent />
</div>
```

End result should be something like this:

```
<!-- b-d7o4hkmt2s is the attribute applied by Blazor, which is an identifier for the component in the DOM -->

<!-- CSS -->

div[b-d7o4hkmt2s] .SomeComponentClass {
    color: blue;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<div b-d7o4hkmt2s> 
    <div class="SomeComponentClass">Some Component Content</div>
<div>
```

Anything outside of the component will not have their CSS updated, CSS isolation is only applied down the DOM tree, not up.